# sybase default while table creation null or not null?

Tags: sybase

I am creating a table in sybase with proeprty 
"overriddenBy varchar(32)".
If i don't define it "null" or "not null" while table creation, will it allow null or not?
I am having issue

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into EntityPnlData(nodeId,
>   hierarchyViewId, entityPnlCriteriaId, receivedFeedId, pnlValue,
>   overridden) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)]; The column overriddenBy in
>   table EntityPnlData does not allow null values.

But it was working fine earlier. I am not sure what could have changed

Comment: Default is NOT NULL in ASE. I am sure it can be changed though but you need to have DBA access to do it. Alter the table to allow NULL values in overriddenBy column

Answer (score 1):

If you set the database option 'allow nulls by default', then columns will always allow NULL except when explicitly specified otherwise.
You can also add the NULL keyword to allow NULLs, i.e. "create table mytab(mycol varchar(32) null)".
Or if the table is already created you can do "alter table mytab modify mycol varchar(32) [not] null". The latter may work only n ASE 15.7 or later.